# How to make Prezi-like graphics in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, prezi

Does anyone know how Prezi (The fancy presentation software) is made ? I need to create an application with a module that includes some graphical features like in Prezi.

I'm talking specifically about the graphical library.

I have been looking to DirectX or XNA but I'm not sure if this would be the right choice...

Any help would be much appreciated :) !

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might not fully understand the "graphical library", but I think the answer you're looking for is that Prezi presentations are rendered in Flash, you can probably "embed" them in your application, are they are available on their website through Flash, or locally on your computer without a browser, with a Flash player.